# Mudar propriedade de um elemento em CSS em determinadas paginas

Tags: css

Para o meu exemplo vou usar uma classe CSS chamada .item

```
.item{
    width:100%;
}
```

Entao, como fazer alterar esta propriedade deste elemento em algumas paginas especificas?

por exemplo, na pagina index qro width 100%, na pagina contato qro 90%, na localização quero 20%.

como fazer isto sem ter q criar um pra cada?

Comment: Eu acho que você precisa criar uma classe para cada página, pra index voce cria `.item-index{ width:100%; }`, para contato `.item-contato{ width:90%; }` e para localização `.item-localização{ width:20%; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só você colocar uma class no `body` da página que você quer que seja diferente, exemplo você coloca a `class="diferente"`,aí no `CSS` ficaria assim:

```
.item{
    width:100%;
}

.diferente .item{
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: Boa, vou fazer isso Kenny... Vlw Fella

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer de algumas formas :

Adicionar uma folha de estilo para cada página. Ex :index.css/contato.css/localizacao.css e chamar cada qual no `head` correspondente.

Ou pode fazer com javascript...

Comment: Vlw fera, mas olha que o Kenny sugeriu, acho q eh melhor... :)

Comment: @RenanDuarte Não foi o Kenny que sugeriu foi a Roberta, É um dos caminhos eu prefiro organizar o estilo dessa forma que falei, pois na minha visão fica mais simples, pra mexer com media queries e tals, mas cada um tem um propósito use a solução que achar melhor e que funcione...Vlw man]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também ignorar a sua classe atual utilizando !important na sua página.

```
.item{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Vlw fera, mas olha que o Kenny sugeriu, acho q eh melhor...